# How to match specific character after another specific character

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, match

I need to find a specific character after another specific character. For example

```
jhony@domain.com
```

I need to find the first occurrence of "." until the **end** of word **after** the first occurrence of "@"

I tried this pattern but I was not successful:

```
(?<=@)([.])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/sTRpxp/1

Comment: Why use regex? maybe use indexOf and substring instead?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, you are right. I use `result = email.substring(email.indexOf("@")).substring(email.substring(email.indexOf("@")).indexOf("."));`

Comment: Don’t use repeated `substring` operations. Instead, use `result = email.substring(email.indexOf('.', email.indexOf('@') + 1));` which literally says “use the index of the first `'.'` after the first `'@'`”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative regex:

```
"(?<=@\\w{1,100})(\\.\\S+)"
```

Regex in context and testbench:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "jhony@domain.com";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=@\\w{1,100})(\\.\\S+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Matching without "group number":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "jhony@domain.com";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=@\\w{1,100})\\.\\S+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.com
```

More about Pattern's 'Special constructs' can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 2):

I think a lookbehind is not necessary.
I rarely use them as I find them quite hard to comprehend. Sometimes you have to use them, but you could try the following:

```
@.*?(\..*)$
```

- Start by matching a literal `@`
- Then just take everything, but not beeing greedy: `.*?`
- Starting the first capturing group with brackets `(...)`
- Match a literal dot with `\.`
- and then just the rest of it `.*`

**Important:** Not beeing greedy using `.*?` allows you to start a capturing group at the **first** occurrence of a literal dot. If you were using `.*` (greedy) you could not capture domains like `.co.uk`, you would only capture `.uk`.

For the following test data:

```
jhony@domain.com
john.doe@company.co.uk
```

you will get `.com` and `.co.uk` in the first capturing group.

Regex101 example: https://regex101.com/r/8iYCJ9/1

Comment: This must be also fine for OP then. The accepted answer added non-whitespace chars, `\S+`, pattern after dot.

Answer (score 2):

Your current problem can probably be solved in a different way, but here is what you ask for:

```java
(?<=@\w{0,255})\.
```

See the maximum length of the host part is [said to be](https://blog.moonmail.io/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-valid-email-address-f712c6c4bc93) 255 chars, `{0,255}` seems to be able to match as many word chars between `@` and `.` as necessary.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nFHNuP/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=@\w{0,255})` - a positive *constrained-width* lookbehind, matching a position that is immediately preceded with `@` and then 0 to 255 word chars
- `\.` - a dot.

Comment: While reading your answer I noticed that I misunderstood the question. I just assumed he wanted to match the TLD, but he only wants to match the dot. This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: @SimonOelerich Right now, yes, the question sounds ambiguous. At any rate, I am happy OP got a solution after all.